# How to determine the sign of the s-wave scattering length?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering

I guess it is relatively easy to determine the magnitude of the scattering length $a$.

We just need to measure the scattering cross section. In this way, we can determine the value of $a^2$.

But how to determine its sign?

Comment: Do you have a specific context in mind? For example, in the context of cold bosonic atoms, you could just try to make a Bose condensate, which would be unstable for negative scattering lengths. The collapse of BEC in this context is studied, for example, [here](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.81.933) or [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.2645)...

Comment: I have in mind a very general problem.

Comment: OK. The first thing that springs to mind is some kind of interferometry protocol. If you can control the positions of the two particles (admittedly a big if), then you could try to measure the phase acquired during a fixed interaction time. Specifically, suppose you can put each particle in a superposition of wave-packets positioned at $x_i$, $y_i$, where $i=1,2$ labels the particles. Then if you keep $x_{1,2}$ well separated, but bring $y_{1,2}$ together, you will get a phase on that branch of the wavefunction proportional to the scattering length and interaction time...

Comment: [contd.]...similar ideas are contained in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9810087).

Comment: So it sounds that there is no efficient method to determine the sign? I thought it is a basic problem in atomic physics or whatever.

Comment: Well in general, you can be deduce it if you know whether the wavefunction is pulled towards the potential region or expelled from it. (negative sign in first case). Maybe with more detail I can help more.

Comment: The method I described would be an efficient way of doing what you ask in the context of atomic physics, where the positions of atoms can be very precisely controlled using laser cooling and laser-induced dipole traps. Generally speaking you are asking about the sign of an energy shift, i.e. whether being in close proximity lowers or raises their energy (in pseudopotential approximation), as @Phonon points out.

Comment: There may also be easy ensemble measurements one could do. For example, measuring the change in the total energy of a trapped atomic cloud as the density is varied. If this change is negative then so is the scattering length (assuming we are only allowing one kind of scattering, e.g. s-wave for cold bosons). This could probably be done quite straightforwardly using a time of flight absorption measurement to find the momentum distribution after switching off the trap. Interferometry will probably give you a more precise measurement though, especially if using entanglement to enhance precision.

Comment: @MarkMitchison If Jian confirms whether these suggestions are in the direction he was looking for, then I think we should sum them up as an answer, specially since you've suggested two nice practical methods.

Comment: @Phonon As a theorist I'd feel a bit better if we could find some experimentalists (either here or in the literature) who also think these methods are practical :) But yeah sure I'll try and formalise this tomorrow.

Comment: @MarkMitchison haha fair enough :)

Comment: All the methods suggested above sound reasonable, but not so direct. Did not people carry out some experiments determining the sign of $a$ in reality?

Answer (score 2):

I think the appropriate method will depend on what system you're studying.  I don't know about a general method, but since you also asked about experiments which determined the sign of $a$, I can offer a specific example:

In ultracold atomic physics experiments there is the case of Feshbach resonance, where you have a large positive scattering length due to a weakly bound state, and then as you adjust the bound state energy across the resonance (by varying the applied magnetic field) the scattering length changes sign.  As was done in [this experiment](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0408673), one can measure the binding energy of the molecules (at various magnetic field strengths) using rf spectroscopy, and then use this information to determine the magnitude and sign of the scattering length.

Comment: I didn't see this answer before I posted, which makes mine a little redundant. I will keep it up but give you a +1.

Answer (score 1):

One way to measure the magnitude is by looking for a density-dependent energy shift. If you transfer atoms between, say, two hyperfine states with a microwave transition, the resonant frequency of this transition will change due to the mean-field shift from the interactions. If you start with an interacting mix of states 1 and 2, and you transfer from state 2 to state 3, you will find that

$\Delta f=\frac{2\hbar}{m}n_1(a_{23}-a_{13})$

This equation comes from the [PhD thesis of Cindy Regal](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0601054), where you may find more information in section 5.3. She used this technique to characterize a Feshbach resonance, for which it is very well-suited.

So this depends on the sign of the scattering length, but clearly it won't always be helpful: one would mainly use it if one scattering length is already known, and if they are identical it is completely useless!

I think the more general answer is rather boring: it is determined by a combination of experimental measurements of the magnitude from scattering experiments plus detailed numerical modeling. In some cases, as Mark Mitchison has said, one might tell from states of matter that depend on the sign, but I'm not aware of any cases in which this has actually been used.

I don't really know if this is the whole story or not, so I welcome any other comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a tricky problem , which appears in several branches of physics (not just atomic physics, but also nuclear and particle physics). If all you have is two-body scattering data you need to look for interference with an amplitude of known sign. In nuclear physics, for example, you can use the sign of the Coulomb amplitude to determine the sign of the strong scattering phase shift.

In a many-body system it is indeed easiest to look at the sign of the mean-field shift, which is directly proportional to $a$.